# Conditional $expand option in ASP.WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created two tables with following columns
Table Name: TBL_Question
Columns:

```
QuestionId
QuestionTitle
QuestionBody
```

Table Name: TBL_Response
Columns:

```
ResponseId 
QuestionId (FK)
ResponseBody
```

After this I used Entity Framework to generate data layer which creates two classes:

1. TBL_Question
2. TB_Response

To return data from ASP.Net WebAPI, I want to return DTO classes, not the classes which are generated by Entity Generator. 
The two DTO classes created for this are:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public string QuestionBody { get; set; }
    public List<Response> Responses { get; set; } 
}

public class Response
{
    public string ResponseId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; } 
    public string ResponseBody { get; set; }
}
```

I created a method in WebAPI which returns the Questions in the following way:

```
public IQueryable<DataList> GetDataLists()
    {
        var query = from a in siteDataRepository.DbContext.Tbl_Question
                    select new Question
                    {
                        QuestionId = a.QuestionId,
                QuestionTitle = a.QuestionTitle,
                QuestionBody=a.QuestionBody,
                Responses = a.Tbl_Response.Select(c1 => new Response
                            {
                                ResponseId=c1.ResponseId,
                                QuestionId=c1.QuestionId,
                ResponseBody=c1.ResponseBody
                            }).ToList(),
                    };

        return siteDataRepository.Search(query);
    }
```

**This method works fine. The Query is:
How I can control that if $expand option is provided only then it fills the Response List. Any idea?**

Comment: `...$expand option is provided..` Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes $expand option is provided. The problem is even if I donot use $expand option, the Responses(the child list) is populated. I want that child list should be populated ONLY when $expand=Responses is passed to the service otherwise it should be empty.